# Why this register mnemonic?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers, calling-convention, abi

From [here](http://csappbook.blogspot.com/2015/08/dianes-silk-dress-costs-89.html) for register order in System V calling conventions they suggest the mnemonic:

```
%rdi:   Diane's
%rsi:   Silk
%rdx:   dress
%rcx:   costs <------------ ???
%r8:    $8
%r9:    9
```

But in my understanding, the 4th register is `r10`, or am I incorrect in this? My source is: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/constants/syscalls.md#calling-conventions.

Comment: Your first link is the calling convention for regular functions, and your second link is the convention for system calls.  The syscall convention can't be the same because the `syscall` instruction implicitly stores the calling address in `rcx`.

Comment: @NateEldredge I see, thank you. So when I write an internal function in assembly I should be using `rcx` (and not `r10`) for the 4th param?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.